# Count of integer values in a List using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, windows, lambda

I have a list like this:

```
        myList.Add(1);
        myList.Add(1);
        myList.Add(3);
        myList.Add(4);
        myList.Add(5);
        myList.Add(6);
```

I want to find the number of '1's upto an index of 4.  So, in this case, the result should be 2.

How do you I put a condition in the `Count()`.

***I need the number of integers, which fulfills the criterion `n<2 && n>0 (i.e. n==1)`***.

Comment: If the first 4 numbers were all 10, and then the next 4 numbers were all 1, what result would you expect?

Comment: BTW if you want the index to go to 4, you need to Take(5)

Comment: @mjwills: in that case, I would expect 0.

Comment: @mjwills: Oh yes...I want the count

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only care abou the first 4 entries in the list (as you said, values with higher indexes don't matter).

So at first, restrict the search to these four numbers:

```
myList.Take(4)
```

from these you want to count only the entries that are `1`. You can achieve that using the `Count()` linq extension that takes a predicate:

```
int numberOfOnes = myList.Take(4).Count(i => i == 1);
```

Comment: Is there any benefit of using `myList.Take(4).Count(i => i == 1);` over `myList.Take(4).Where(n=>(n==1)).Sum();` ?

Comment: `myList.Take(4).Where(n=>(n==1)).Sum();` looks more like a workaround for counting the number of `1`s.

Comment: @skm in this specific case: yes, I don't need to go through these 4 elements twice. The sum of `n` `1`s is `n`. Of course, the performance impact on a list of 4 elements should not be measurable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = myList.Take(4).Where(w=>w == 1).Sum()
```

Additionally, 'Where' has a less commonly used overload that provides the index: `myList.Where((w,ix)=>ix < 4 && w == 1).Sum().`

I would probably use .Take() for readability and performance reasons (see @mjwills comment) though.

Comment: The latter solution will be slower since it is forced to iterate over the entire list.

Comment: +1 (and delete my similar answer as redundant) for the `Where` with the index as fitting the criteria in a looser way. I would though still use the `Take` when applicable as being more efficient (whether it's more readable or not is harder to say, the `Where` with index more directly reflects the criteria given, so arguably that's more readable).